# Labelling nodes in a weighted graph and obtaining the number of nodes in connected component

Tags: python, graph, label, nodes

i am trying to do this exercise but I am struggling a bit.
Here is what is asked:

Write the function labelize_cc(g: Graph, x: int, label: int) -> int that sets the label of the nodes
in the connected component of x to the value label and returns the number of nodes in the connected component.

The following code is necesarry:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Node:
  succ: list
  label: int = -1"
```

An example of graph would be this:

```
MyGraph = [Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(13, 0.62)]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(19, 0.45)]),
 Node(succ=[(14, 0.55)]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(11, 0.67)]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(7, 0.67), (13, 0.69)]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(2, 0.62), (11, 0.69), (17, 0.85)]),
 Node(succ=[(5, 0.55)]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(13, 0.85)]),
 Node(succ=[]),
 Node(succ=[(4, 0.45)])]
```

The main problem I have is that i can't access succesors (tuple element in a list) with simple interation.
Can someone please help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "with simple interation. "  What's that?  Perhaps you mean iteration?  Post the code where you tried and show what goes wrong.